# how to load a JSON file to solr using `pysolr`?

Tags: solr, pysolr

The following python code adds a document but without the json contents:

```
solr_instance = pysolr.Solr('http://192.168.45.153:8983/solr/test', timeout=60)
json_filename = '/path/to/file/test.json'
argws = {
    'commit': 'true',
    'extractOnly': False,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
with open(json_filename, 'rb') as f:
    solr_instance.extract(f, **argws)
    solr_instance.commit()
```

using `curl` from the command line works as expected:

```
$ curl 'http://192.168.45.153:8983/solr/test/update?commit=true' \
     --data-binary @/path/to/file/test.json \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

the file has following content:

```
$ cat /cygdrive/w/mist/test.json
-->    [{"x": "a","y": "b"}]
```

I'm using `pysolr 3.6.0` and `solr 6.5.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `extract()` method refers to a request made against the ExtractingRequestHandler, which is meant to be used for extracting content from rich documents (such as PDFs, etc.).

You can use the regular `.add` method to submit the decoded JSON to Solr:

```
import json

solr.add(json.load(json_filename))
```

.. should work.

Comment: This works. But I get an error `Document contains at least one immense term in field="x" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.` (I showed a small document in my example)

Comment: Open a new question for new questions, but it's probably related to having a `string` field with a length above 32766 (since a string field is indexed as a single term).